# Decreasing function with a fixed point and 2 cycle?

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

Can you give me an example of a decreasing function with a fixed point and 2-cycle?

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ (on the positive reals) has a fixed point and a great many $2$-cycles.